# How to instantiate NSViewController from a Framework on OS X (i.e. getting the correct bundle)

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xib, nsbundle, ios-frameworks

How can I instantiate a view controller from framework added to my OS X App *(this may actually be the same process as iOS, I'm unsure, last time I looked Frameworks where not allowed on iOS but that may have changed*)?

**Here is the setup:**

- Private framework `MyFramework.framework`,
- containing a view controller `CustomViewController`,
- with XIB `CustomViewController.xib`.

**What does not work**

`CustomViewController(nibName: "CustomViewController", bundle:nil)` will not work because the resources are *not* in the App's main bundle (they are in the framework).

**What does work**

To instantiate view controllers from the framework my App using the following code (it works!) which iterates through all loaded frameworks using `NSBundle.allFrameworks()` and picks out my framework by comparing the `bundleIdentifier`,

```
func findMyFrameworkBundle() -> NSBundle? {
    if let frameworkBundles = NSBundle.allFrameworks() as? [NSBundle] {
        for bundle in frameworkBundles {
            if let identifier = bundle.bundleIdentifier {
                if identifier == "com.Me.MyFramework" {
                    return bundle
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

let nibName = "CustomViewController"
let bundle = findMyFrameworkBundle()
let viewController = CustomViewController(nibName:nibName, bundle:bundle)
```

**How to improve?**

This seems overly complex which make me think that I must be doing something wrong. Some potential solutions:

1. Can I change my framework and provide custom initialiser which always instantiates view controller with the correct bundle?

For example,

```
class CustomViewController : NSViewController {

    init() {

        let bundle = // ... the correct bundle even when used as an embedded framework in an App
        super.init(nibName: "CustomViewController", bundle: bundle)
    }

    // ... other code
}
```

2. Is there a better way of providing the correct bundle in my App rather than search through `NSBundle.allFrameworks()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but I think standard practice is to use the `NSBundle` constructor that takes an identifier as its only argument. As in:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(identifier: "com.Me.MyFramework")!
```

Comment: I have made new initialisers for all of my view controllers in the framework and load the bundle as you suggest. It works! This makes the bundle loading transparent for the user. Thanks.